# Pgfgantt: grid lines and title separators according to title tier

Tags: diagrams, pgfgantt

[image: ScreenShot]I am trying to organize a gantt chart according to year and quarter. I am unable to format the grid and title-table lines.

1. I am unable have the horizontal lines within the title section to be independent of the vertical line formatting. That is, the two red-arrow-annotated horizontal lines are currently dashed, that I wanted to be solid.
2. I am unable to have the vertical lines within the title section and the main chart to be dependent on the year and quarter formatting. That is, the green-arrow-annotated vertical lines and the two blue-arrow-annotated grid lines in the chart to be solid, which are currently dashed.

Here is the code for the screenshot posted based on an online example.

```
\ganttset{group/.append style={orange},
milestone/.append style={red},
progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}}

\begin{ganttchart}[%Specs
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=0.7cm,
     vgrid = {*2{black, dotted},*1{black,dashed}},
     hgrid = true,
     title height=1,
       expand chart=\textwidth,
%     title/.style={fill=none},
     title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
     bar/.style={fill=blue},
     bar height=0.7,
%   progress label text={},
     group right shift=0,
     group top shift=0.7,
     group height=.3,
     group peaks width={0.2},
     inline]{1}{36}
    %labels
    % \gantttitle{A three-years project}{36}\\  
    % % title 1
    \gantttitlelist[
        title/.style={draw=black}]{"Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3"}{12}\\
    % \gantttitle[]{Year 1}{12}                 
    % % title 2
    % \gantttitle[]{Year 2}{12} 
    % % title 3
    % \gantttitle[]{Year 3}{12} \\
    % %
    \gantttitlelist[
        title/.style={draw=black, dashed, inner color=red}]{"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4",
        "Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4",
        "Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"}{3} \\
    % Setting group if any
    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 1}{1}{5}\\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=10,inline=false]{Planning}{1}{4}\\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 1}{9} \\

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 2}{6}{12} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=2,inline=false]{test1}{10}{19} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 2}{17} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=5,inline=false]{test2}{11}{20} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 3}{22} \\       

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 3}{13}{24} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=90,inline=false]{Task A}{13}{15} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=50,inline=false, bar progress label node/.append style={below left= 10pt and 7pt}]{Task B}{13}{24} \\ \\
    \ganttbar[progress=30,inline=false]{Task C}{15}{16}\\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=70,inline=false]{Task D}{18}{20} \\ 
\end{ganttchart}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please make sure, the code you post does compile when we copy it. Yours doesn't. I.e. please replace the ... by codelines which make it compile AND is minimal AND still shows your problem. // Also a screenshot might help (the one you perhaps tried was lost).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can always manually add things to a `pgfgantt` chart using basic Ti*k*Z commands. You just need to scale `x` and `y` correctly, but you can use commands provided by the `pgfgantt` package for this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\ganttset{
    group/.append style={orange},
    milestone/.append style={red},
    progress label node anchor/.append style={text=red}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    y unit title=0.5cm,
    y unit chart=0.7cm,
    vgrid={*2{black, dotted}, *1{black, dashed}},
    hgrid=true,
    title height=1,
    expand chart=\textwidth,
    title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
    bar/.style={fill=blue},
    bar height=0.7,
    group right shift=0,
    group top shift=0.7,
    group height=.3,
    group peaks width={0.2},
    inline
]{1}{36}
    \gantttitlelist[
        title/.style={draw=black}
    ]{"Year 1", "Year 2", "Year 3"}{12} \\
    \gantttitlelist[
        title/.append style={draw=none, inner color=red},
        vgrid={*2{black, dotted}, *1{black, dashed}},
    ]{ 
        "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4",
        "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4",
        "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"
    }{3} \\

    \begin{scope}[x=\ganttvalueof{x unit}, y=\ganttvalueof{y unit title}]
        \draw (0,-1) rectangle +({12 * 3},-1);
        \foreach \y in {1,2} {
            \draw ({\y*4*3},-1) -- +(0,-1);
        }
        \foreach \q in {1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11} {
            \draw[dashed] ({\q*3},-1) -- +(0,-1);
        }
    \end{scope}

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 1}{1}{5} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=10, inline=false]{Planning}{1}{4} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 1}{9} \\

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 2}{6}{12} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=2, inline=false]{test1}{10}{19} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 2}{17} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=5, inline=false]{test2}{11}{20} \\
    \ganttmilestone[inline=false]{Milestone 3}{22} \\       

    \ganttgroup[inline=false]{Group 3}{13}{24} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=90, inline=false]{Task A}{13}{15} \\ 
    \ganttbar[
        progress=50, 
        inline=false, 
        bar progress label node/.append style={below left=10pt and 7pt}
    ]{Task B}{13}{24} \\ 
        \\
    \ganttbar[progress=30,inline=false]{Task C}{15}{16} \\ 
    \ganttbar[progress=70,inline=false]{Task D}{18}{20} \\ 
\end{ganttchart} 
\end{document}
```

[image]